# iOS app development (iPad) : Does Swift support self designed GUI and openGL?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I am a beginner of iOS app development. I have already finished a program in Windows using Qt with openGL. Now I'm going to develop an iOS version, exactly iPad. However, they are quite different.

I plan to use Xcode and Swift to develop the iOS version. And I'm wondering whether Swift support self designed GUI, like CSS, and openGL. They are both necessary part of my app.

If not, is there any powerful GUI design tools for iOS app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Swift does not use HTML or CSS but there are built in objects like buttons and text fields that have an attributes inspector and you can change their properties there such as size color border etc. you set their constraints indidually or in groups using constraints. There is an OpenGL alternative for swift but I have never used it and can only recomend it as far as to say it exists http://www.swiftgl.org/